# skip directory in URl by using Rewriting Rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a web-page with is located in example/files/page.php in my server. I would like to use Rewrite Rules in order to skip the /files directory in the URl so when the user types example/page.php to be able to view the content of the page.php. How is it possible to do so with Rewrite Rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the .htaccess in the *root* directory of your website.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(example)/(.*)$ /$1/files/$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken this piece of code should be located in the /example directory right?