# How to skip a directory in a URI using NGINX?

Tags: php, url, nginx, uri, nginx-location

So I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036104/skip-directory-in-url-by-using-rewriting-rules), but it didn't seem related to this question.

My situation is, I have a directory on my website called `mywebsite.com/indev/dist` (since `dist` is the build folder). I want all the files in `mywebsite.com/indev/dist` to appear and work as if the `dist` folder didn't exist at all.

For example, if I requested `mywebsite.com/indev/index45.php`, the file would be located at `/indev/dist/index45.php`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
location ~ .*\/indev\/dist.* {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ .*\/indev.* {
  rewrite ^\/indev\/(.*) /indev/dist/$1 break;
}
```

This works fine with one major drawback: php files don't run, they go to the original address which gives a 404 in return. Is there any way to do what I'm using using the NGINX config without any major drawbacks (or having to make unnecessary rules (ex. just to handle php files)?)

Comment: Do all the URIs begin with `/indev`? So what you are trying to do is alias `/indev/` to `/indev/dist/`. For PHP to work, you will need to use a nested `location`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287201/wordpress-laravel-and-nginx/45297857#45297857).

Comment: Awesome! That does exactly what I needed. Thank you very, very much!